# Multiple target frameworks for ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently I'm migrating ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API to .NET 6.0. But I'd like to support the 3.1 version for a while, as on some servers only the .NET Core 3.1 version is installed.

Is there a way to target both 3.1 and 6 version of .NET Core for the Web API? The way, the `dotnet pack` will generate binaries for both versions. Something similar, to multi target frameworks for the libraries. Like

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net6.0<TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: You would need to include these also `<AspNetCoreTargetVersion>3.1</AspNetCoreTargetVersion>
    <AspNetCoreTargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</AspNetCoreTargetFramework>` because the <TargetFrameworks> specifies the target frameworks, and `<AspNetCoreTargetVersion>` and `<AspNetCoreTargetFramework>` are used to specify the target ASP.NET Core version. You may need to adjust additional settings in the project file based on your specific requirements.